# ESP01 and Arduino - Serial port confusion

Tags: arduino-uno, uart, esp

I'm trying to understand how to think about ESP01 devices and arduino connectivity

I purchased one of the [USB programmers](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/ESP-01-ESP8266-Switchable-USB-Adaptor-Programmer-CH340G-UK-Seller/322466871464?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649) from Ebay to program the ESP01 - this works nicely, I can see the ESP doing things (I have it pinging a server sending data back and forth)

Obviously, the ESP01 has very few GPIO pins, so I'm interested in connecting to an arduino so I can combine the Arduino's IO with the Wifi on the ESP, and this is where I'm getting a little stuck. I'm assuming I have to connect the RX pin on the Uno to the TX on the ESP and the TX on the Uno to the ESP RX to set up the connection, but I'm confused as to which serial port to use on the Uno.

Specifically:

- are the TX/RX pins on the arduino actually the same serial port as the USB connector - i.e if my intent is to plug the arduino into a computer to talk to it over USB, should I not then re-use the TX/RX pins to talk to the ESP
- if so, should I look to software serial or something similar and use other IO pins on the arduino to connect to the ESP01

... Also, as an aside, if I get this all working, do I still need the USB programmer, or can I then program directly from the arduino?

Comment: yes and yes. and you can use the Arduino to upload to esp-01, but it is not so simple. I recommend you to upload a firmware to esp-01 with the programmer and use a corresponding library in Arduino. for example https://github.com/jandrassy/WiFiEspAT

Comment: Cool - thanks, so the first yes, is that the RX/TX pins are the same serial connection the USB port uses? (just making sure I fully understand)

Comment: yes. Atmega328p has only one UART  peripheral for hardware Serial.

Comment: It's a pity that all newbies get hooked on the artificial (and false) necessity of combine ESP01 and Arduino in a single project. A newbie should let the complexities of attaching one device to another to the future, and just start with a ESP8266 version with more GPIOs, like ESP12.

Comment: @mguima, esp8266 was developed to be used as WiFi adapter, not as standalone MCU. do you want to write sketches for CC2541 on HC-11 BLE adapter? it is a MCU too.

Comment: @juraj, this question is dumb and pointless. **I didn't say anything about writing sketches for CC2541 or for HC11 - or for TMS1000, neither.** But, for most of the things that a newbie could want to do, simple things like blink a LED or switch a relay, **an ESP8266 is enough**, and, YES, in a non-critical environment, ESP8266 can be used as a standalone CPU. A professional that would **REALLY** need to use Arduino **and** ESP8266 surely would not asking for help here in StackExchange. But, most of times, using ESP8266 as a Wifi adapter for an Arduino is just a unnecessary and complicated hype

Comment: @juraj **It's NOT TRUE** that _"esp8266 was developed to be used as WiFi adapter, not as standalone MCU"._  It seems that you said that only for disagree with what I said. Can you point to sources for this information? ESP8266 [datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/0a-esp8266ex_datasheet_en.pdf) says _"With the complete and self-contained Wi-Fi networking capabilities, ESP8266EX can perform either as a standalone application or as the slave to a host MCU."_  If it were intented to be just a WiFi adapter, why would it have peripherals and available GPIO's?

Comment: @mguima, it doesn't say with what goal it was developed. It would be very strange to waste so many pins for boot configuration on a standalone MCU. Most of the  docs are about integration with a host MCU. There was no published SDK initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino UNO only has one serial port. That is pins 0/1 (RX and TX), which is mapped to the `Serial` object.

Those pins and that object are also used for communication with the PC through the USB connection. That means you can't easily use them for both PC communication and ESP8266 communication. It's possible, but it gets messy.

That is why many people use `SoftwareSerial` because that can work on any combination of pins on the Arduino that you like.

> ... Also, as an aside, if I get this all working, do I still need the USB programmer, or can I then program directly from the arduino?

Again, that is possible, but very messy. You could possibly get things to pass through from `Serial` to a `SoftwareSerial` instance, but it's not reliable (`SoftwareSerial` in general is not reliable for sustained transfers of data), and using the Arduino as a dumb UART interface would entail changing the wiring to pins 0/1 when you wanted to program.

So it's far simple to just use your USB interface for programming. Either that or set up OTA programming for the ESP8266 so you don't even have to use wires.

Comment: This is great, thanks for the guidance.